# How do we change default drop down values in Date Time field for Time drop down?

Tags: datetime, date, time

I have a Date Time field, in Time Drop down the values display as 12.00 am, 12.15 am, 12.30 am and so on, but i need only to show interval with 1 hr, like 12 am, 1 am, 2 am and so on.
Please help on this?

Thanks,
Hari Krishna

Answer (score 0):

While we can customize many things in Salesforce, there's no setting to control the values. They are always rendered this way for all date-time fields.